# Positioning a nested DIV relative to the page and not the first positioned ancestor

Tags: html, css, positioning

Is there any way to position a nested DIV (or any other nested HTML element) relative to the page (so `0,0` would put it at the top left of the page) when it has a positioned ancestor, without using javascript.

Using `position:fixed` won't work because this positions it relative to the viewport, so it does not move if the page is scrolled.

Using `position:absolute` won't work since I am asking about a nested DIV with a positioned ancestor. This would cause the position will be relative to the positioned ancestor.

Comment: Only if the outer elements left/top position is known/fixed.

Comment: @LGSon not only that but also every of the parents top/left needs to be fixed for what you're thinking...

Comment: @sam - In short, no. Post some code or make a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

No, that can't be done without script ...

... unless the outer element's left/top position is known/fixed, like in this example

```css
.nr1,
.nr2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.nr1 {
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.nr2 {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nr1">
  <div class="nr2">
  </div>
</div>
```